# ¿Como solucionar problemas de cache en servidor?

Tags: cache

Tengo un problema que es que no se me actualiza ningun archivo de mi servidor, tengo entendido que es por el cache y se 'soluciona' con un "?" por ej.

```
$NumRandom = rand(1,50);
<img src="images/casa/1.jpeg?<?php echo $NumRandom ?>" width="100%"> <?php }
```

Lo que sucede es que también utilizo includes y no me deja poner

```
include 'ubicacion.php?'.$NumRandom;
```

porque me da error y la verdad ya no se que hacer

No puedo ver el progreso de mi web y los cambios que le voy aplicando por este problema

Comment: Haber si te entiendo, lo que dices es que cada vez que le haces una modificación a tu página subes los archivos al servidor y cuando entras a un navegador los cambios no se ven? A eso te refieres

Comment: Así es, tambien hay veces que elimino una imagen o le cambio el nombre y al actualizar la página en donde estaba la imagen (y una vez eliminada no debería estar) sigue estando, lo que sucede es tengo un código php con html que lo llamo en un include pero ese include no se me actualiza por el cache, no sé que hacer

Comment: Abre tu página en una pestaña en incógnito en tu navegador y fijate si sigue pasando. Si no pasa entonces si es el cache

Comment: No pasa, he probado con Ctrl + Shift + R, Ctrl + F5, desde el celular, desde una notebook, ¿como lo puedo arreglar?

Comment: Lo que esta pasando es que cada vez que alguien entra a tu página se está guardando en el cache del navegador. Agrega en la etiqueta head de tu html el siguiente código <meta http-equiv =»Cache-Control» content =»no-cache»/>

Comment: <meta http-equiv ="Cache-Control" content ="no-cache" />